# ZMK nice!60 does not pair with Ubuntu?

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-20.04

I've just built my first custom keyboard and I'm having a problem getting it to pair.

I have a [nice!60 pcb](https://nicekeyboards.com/docs/nice-60/getting-started) and I'm trying to get it to pair with Ubuntu 20.04. When I first turned it on it worked fairly well, but a day later and it won't connect at all.

I've tried the following:

1. clearing out the host profiles and reconnecting
2. resetting the pcb
3. resetting Ubuntu's bluetooth service
4. connecting to a different Ubuntu 20.04 device

I get the same problem everytime. I attempt to pair the device, and either Ubuntu automatically rejects the pairing or the wheel spins then the settings dialogue freezes.

Any ideas? I would appreciate any help.

I am updating this post based on Mr. Panda's suggestion. Here is the output for `sudo btmon`:

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.53
= Note: Linux version 5.11.0-25-generic (x86_64)                                            0.090103
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                    0.090106
= New Index: E4:AA:EA:91:B6:74 (Primary,USB,hci0)                                    [hci0] 0.090107
= Open Index: E4:AA:EA:91:B6:74                                                      [hci0] 0.090108
= Index Info: E4:AA:EA:91:B6:74 (Realtek Semiconductor Corporation)                  [hci0] 0.090109
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.19                                  {0x0001} 0.090110
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.19                                       {0x0003} 0.090111
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.19                                       {0x0002} 0.090113
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.19                                       {0x0004} 0.090131
@ MGMT Command: Set IO Capability (0x0018) plen 1                           {0x0001} [hci0] 7.807312
        Capability: DisplayYesNo (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 3                              {0x0001} [hci0] 7.807344
      Set IO Capability (0x0018) plen 0
        Status: Success (0x00)
@ MGMT Command: Start Service Discovery (0x003a) plen 4                     {0x0001} [hci0] 7.960487
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        RSSI: invalid (0x7f)
        UUIDs: 0
< HCI Command: LE Set Random Address (0x08|0x0005) plen 6                         #1 [hci0] 7.960616
        Address: 19:43:66:59:9C:83 (Non-Resolvable)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                       #2 [hci0] 8.076901
      LE Set Random Address (0x08|0x0005) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) plen 8               #3 [hci0] 8.076958
        Own address type: Random (0x01)
        Filter policy: Accept all advertisement (0x00)
        PHYs: 0x01
        Entry 0: LE 1M
          Type: Active (0x01)
          Interval: 22.500 msec (0x0024)
          Window: 11.250 msec (0x0012)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                       #4 [hci0] 8.077900
      LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) plen 6                   #5 [hci0] 8.077933
        Extended scan: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                       #6 [hci0] 8.078899
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) plen 5                                       #7 [hci0] 8.078928
        Access code: 0x9e8b33 (General Inquiry)
        Length: 10.24s (0x08)
        Num responses: 0
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                         #8 [hci0] 8.079898
      Inquiry (0x01|0x0001) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 4                              {0x0001} [hci0] 8.079937
      Start Service Discovery (0x003a) plen 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                   {0x0004} [hci0] 8.079961
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Enabled (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                   {0x0001} [hci0] 8.079961
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Enabled (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                   {0x0003} [hci0] 8.079961
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Enabled (0x01)
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                   {0x0002} [hci0] 8.079961
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Enabled (0x01)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 70                                         #9 [hci0] 8.114904
      LE Extended Advertising Report (0x0d)
        Num reports: 2
        Entry 0
          Event type: 0x0013
            Props: 0x0013
              Connectable
              Scannable
              Use legacy advertising PDUs
            Data status: Complete
          Legacy PDU Type: ADV_IND (0x0013)
          Address type: Public (0x00)
          Address: 00:1C:97:16:A7:68 (Enzytek Technology Inc.,)
          Primary PHY: LE 1M
          Secondary PHY: No packets
          SID: no ADI field (0xff)
          TX power: 127 dBm
          RSSI: -67 dBm (0xbd)
          Periodic advertising invteral: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
          Direct address type: Public (0x00)
          Direct address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
          Data length: 0x14
        02 01 06 03 03 20 18 0c 09 42 41 52 57 32 37 30  ..... ...BARW270
        41 37 36 38                                      A768            
        Entry 1
          Event type: 0x001b
            Props: 0x001b
              Connectable
              Scannable
              Scan response
              Use legacy advertising PDUs
            Data status: Complete
          Legacy PDU Type: SCAN_RSP to an ADV_SCAN_IND (0x001b)
          Address type: Public (0x00)
          Address: 00:1C:97:16:A7:68 (Enzytek Technology Inc.,)
          Primary PHY: LE 1M
          Secondary PHY: No packets
          SID: no ADI field (0xff)
          TX power: 127 dBm
          RSSI: -67 dBm (0xbd)
          Periodic advertising invteral: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
          Direct address type: Public (0x00)
          Direct address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
          Data length: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Found (0x0012) plen 34                                 {0x0004} [hci0] 8.114955
        LE Address: 00:1C:97:16:A7:68 (Enzytek Technology Inc.,)
        RSSI: -67 dBm (0xbd)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 20
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          Internet Protocol Support (0x1820)
        Name (complete): BARW270A768
@ MGMT Event: Device Found (0x0012) plen 34                                 {0x0001} [hci0] 8.114955
        LE Address: 00:1C:97:16:A7:68 (Enzytek Technology Inc.,)
        RSSI: -67 dBm (0xbd)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 20
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          Internet Protocol Support (0x1820)
        Name (complete): BARW270A768
@ MGMT Event: Device Found (0x0012) plen 34                                 {0x0003} [hci0] 8.114955
        LE Address: 00:1C:97:16:A7:68 (Enzytek Technology Inc.,)
        RSSI: -67 dBm (0xbd)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 20
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          Internet Protocol Support (0x1820)
        Name (complete): BARW270A768
@ MGMT Event: Device Found (0x0012) plen 34                                 {0x0002} [hci0] 8.114955
        LE Address: 00:1C:97:16:A7:68 (Enzytek Technology Inc.,)
        RSSI: -67 dBm (0xbd)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 20
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (complete): 1 entry
          Internet Protocol Support (0x1820)
        Name (complete): BARW270A768
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 72                                        #10 [hci0] 8.184906
      LE Extended Advertising Report (0x0d)
        Num reports: 2
        Entry 0
          Event type: 0x0013
            Props: 0x0013
              Connectable
              Scannable
              Use legacy advertising PDUs
            Data status: Complete
          Legacy PDU Type: ADV_IND (0x0013)
          Address type: Random (0x01)
          Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
          Primary PHY: LE 1M
          Secondary PHY: No packets
          SID: no ADI field (0xff)
          TX power: 127 dBm
          RSSI: -85 dBm (0xab)
          Periodic advertising invteral: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
          Direct address type: Public (0x00)
          Direct address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
          Data length: 0x16
        08 09 6e 69 63 65 21 36 30 03 19 c1 03 02 01 06  ..nice!60.......
        05 02 12 18 0f 18                                ......          
        Entry 1
          Event type: 0x001b
            Props: 0x001b
              Connectable
              Scannable
              Scan response
              Use legacy advertising PDUs
            Data status: Complete
          Legacy PDU Type: SCAN_RSP to an ADV_SCAN_IND (0x001b)
          Address type: Random (0x01)
          Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
          Primary PHY: LE 1M
          Secondary PHY: No packets
          SID: no ADI field (0xff)
          TX power: 127 dBm
          RSSI: -85 dBm (0xab)
          Periodic advertising invteral: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
          Direct address type: Public (0x00)
          Direct address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
          Data length: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Found (0x0012) plen 36                                 {0x0004} [hci0] 8.184951
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        RSSI: -85 dBm (0xab)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 22
        Name (complete): nice!60
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 2 entries
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
          Battery Service (0x180f)
@ MGMT Event: Device Found (0x0012) plen 36                                 {0x0001} [hci0] 8.184951
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        RSSI: -85 dBm (0xab)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 22
        Name (complete): nice!60
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 2 entries
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
          Battery Service (0x180f)
@ MGMT Event: Device Found (0x0012) plen 36                                 {0x0003} [hci0] 8.184951
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        RSSI: -85 dBm (0xab)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 22
        Name (complete): nice!60
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 2 entries
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
          Battery Service (0x180f)
@ MGMT Event: Device Found (0x0012) plen 36                                 {0x0002} [hci0] 8.184951
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        RSSI: -85 dBm (0xab)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 22
        Name (complete): nice!60
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 2 entries
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
          Battery Service (0x180f)
@ MGMT Command: Stop Discovery (0x0024) plen 1                              {0x0001} [hci0] 9.838171
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
< HCI Command: Inquiry Cancel (0x01|0x0002) plen 0                               #11 [hci0] 9.838269
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                      #12 [hci0] 9.840956
      Inquiry Cancel (0x01|0x0002) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) plen 6                  #13 [hci0] 9.840993
        Extended scan: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                      #14 [hci0] 9.841954
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 4                              {0x0001} [hci0] 9.841987
      Stop Discovery (0x0024) plen 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                   {0x0004} [hci0] 9.842001
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Disabled (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                   {0x0001} [hci0] 9.842001
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Disabled (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                   {0x0003} [hci0] 9.842001
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Disabled (0x00)
@ MGMT Event: Discovering (0x0013) plen 2                                   {0x0002} [hci0] 9.842001
        Address type: 0x07
          BR/EDR
          LE Public
          LE Random
        Discovery: Disabled (0x00)
@ MGMT Command: Pair Device (0x0019) plen 8                                 {0x0001} [hci0] 9.846328
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Capability: DisplayYesNo (0x01)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) plen 8              #15 [hci0] 9.846415
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in white list (0x01)
        PHYs: 0x01
        Entry 0: LE 1M
          Type: Passive (0x00)
          Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                      #16 [hci0] 9.847959
      LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) plen 6                  #17 [hci0] 9.848008
        Extended scan: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                      #18 [hci0] 9.848954
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 48                                       #19 [hci0] 10.093956
      LE Extended Advertising Report (0x0d)
        Num reports: 1
        Entry 0
          Event type: 0x0013
            Props: 0x0013
              Connectable
              Scannable
              Use legacy advertising PDUs
            Data status: Complete
          Legacy PDU Type: ADV_IND (0x0013)
          Address type: Random (0x01)
          Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
          Primary PHY: LE 1M
          Secondary PHY: No packets
          SID: no ADI field (0xff)
          TX power: 127 dBm
          RSSI: -75 dBm (0xb5)
          Periodic advertising invteral: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
          Direct address type: Public (0x00)
          Direct address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
          Data length: 0x16
        08 09 6e 69 63 65 21 36 30 03 19 c1 03 02 01 06  ..nice!60.......
        05 02 12 18 0f 18                                ......          
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) plen 6                 #20 [hci0] 10.094019
        Extended scan: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                     #21 [hci0] 10.094959
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Extended Create Connection (0x08|0x0043) plen 26              #22 [hci0] 10.094988
        Filter policy: White list is not used (0x00)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Initiating PHYs: 0x01
        Entry 0: LE 1M
          Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Scan window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Min connection interval: 30.00 msec (0x0018)
          Max connection interval: 50.00 msec (0x0028)
          Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
          Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
          Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
          Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                       #23 [hci0] 10.095960
      LE Extended Create Connection (0x08|0x0043) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                                       #24 [hci0] 10.172966
      LE Connection Complete (0x01)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 16
        Role: Master (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Connection interval: 45.00 msec (0x0024)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Master clock accuracy: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 35                            {0x0004} [hci0] 10.173008
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 22
        Name (complete): nice!60
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 2 entries
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
          Battery Service (0x180f)
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 35                            {0x0001} [hci0] 10.173008
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 22
        Name (complete): nice!60
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 2 entries
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
          Battery Service (0x180f)
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 35                            {0x0003} [hci0] 10.173008
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 22
        Name (complete): nice!60
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 2 entries
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
          Battery Service (0x180f)
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 35                            {0x0002} [hci0] 10.173008
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Flags: 0x00000000
        Data length: 22
        Name (complete): nice!60
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 2 entries
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
          Battery Service (0x180f)
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2                #25 [hci0] 10.173126
        Handle: 16
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                       #26 [hci0] 10.173970
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 16 flags 0x02 dlen 6                                      #27 [hci0] 10.195230
      SMP: Security Request (0x0b) len 1
        Authentication requirement: Bonding, No MITM, SC, No Keypresses (0x09)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 4                                        #28 [hci0] 10.195963
      LE Channel Selection Algorithm (0x14)
        Handle: 16
        Algorithm: #2 (0x01)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                       #29 [hci0] 10.240982
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 16
        Features: 0x7d 0x49 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Extended Reject Indication
          Slave-initiated Features Exchange
          LE Ping
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
          LL Privacy
          LE 2M PHY
          LE Coded PHY
          Channel Selection Algorithm #2
          Minimum Number of Used Channels Procedure
< ACL Data TX: Handle 16 flags 0x00 dlen 11                                     #30 [hci0] 10.241087
      SMP: Pairing Request (0x01) len 6
        IO capability: DisplayYesNo (0x01)
        OOB data: Authentication data not present (0x00)
        Authentication requirement: Bonding, MITM, SC, No Keypresses, CT2 (0x2d)
        Max encryption key size: 16
        Initiator key distribution: EncKey Sign LinkKey (0x0d)
        Responder key distribution: EncKey IdKey Sign LinkKey (0x0f)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 16 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                      #31 [hci0] 10.241372
      ATT: Exchange MTU Request (0x02) len 2
        Client RX MTU: 517
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                          #32 [hci0] 10.331977
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 16
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                          #33 [hci0] 10.332970
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 16
        Count: 1
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 11                                       #34 [hci0] 10.333970
      LE Data Length Change (0x07)
        Handle: 16
        Max TX octets: 27
        Max TX time: 2120
        Max RX octets: 27
        Max RX time: 2120
> ACL Data RX: Handle 16 flags 0x02 dlen 6                                      #35 [hci0] 10.375019
      SMP: Pairing Failed (0x05) len 1
        Reason: Authentication requirements (0x03)
@ MGMT Event: Authentication Failed (0x0011) plen 8                        {0x0004} [hci0] 10.375054
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Status: Authentication Failed (0x05)
@ MGMT Event: Authentication Failed (0x0011) plen 8                        {0x0003} [hci0] 10.375054
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Status: Authentication Failed (0x05)
@ MGMT Event: Authentication Failed (0x0011) plen 8                        {0x0002} [hci0] 10.375054
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Status: Authentication Failed (0x05)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 10                            {0x0001} [hci0] 10.375068
      Pair Device (0x0019) plen 7
        Status: Authentication Failed (0x05)
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3                                  #36 [hci0] 10.375092
        Handle: 16
        Reason: Authentication Failure (0x05)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 16 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                      #37 [hci0] 10.375774
      ATT: Exchange MTU Response (0x03) len 2
        Server RX MTU: 65
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                       #38 [hci0] 10.376971
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                  #39 [hci0] 10.420978
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 16
        Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                          {0x0004} [hci0] 10.421028
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Reason: Connection terminated by local host (0x02)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                          {0x0001} [hci0] 10.421028
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Reason: Connection terminated by local host (0x02)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                          {0x0003} [hci0] 10.421028
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Reason: Connection terminated by local host (0x02)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                          {0x0002} [hci0] 10.421028
        LE Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
        Reason: Connection terminated by local host (0x02)
```

And also updated for gattool:

```
Bluetooth monitor ver 5.53
= Note: Linux version 5.11.0-25-generic (x86_64)                                            0.847931
= Note: Bluetooth subsystem version 2.22                                                    0.847933
= New Index: E4:AA:EA:91:B6:74 (Primary,USB,hci0)                                    [hci0] 0.847933
= Open Index: E4:AA:EA:91:B6:74                                                      [hci0] 0.847934
= Index Info: E4:AA:EA:91:B6:74 (Realtek Semiconductor Corporation)                  [hci0] 0.847935
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.19                                       {0x0004} 0.847935
@ MGMT Open: bluetoothd (privileged) version 1.19                                  {0x0001} 0.847936
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.19                                       {0x0003} 0.847937
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.19                                       {0x0002} 0.847937
@ MGMT Open: btmon (privileged) version 1.19                                       {0x0005} 0.847946
< HCI Command: LE Remove Device From White List (0x08|0x0012) plen 7             #1 [hci0] 41.843380
        Address type: Random (0x01)
        Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (Static)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                      #2 [hci0] 41.957628
      LE Remove Device From White List (0x08|0x0012) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Add Device To White List (0x08|0x0011) plen 7                  #3 [hci0] 41.957726
        Address type: Public (0x00)
        Address: E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB (OUI E7-2D-83)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                      #4 [hci0] 41.958628
      LE Add Device To White List (0x08|0x0011) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) plen 8              #5 [hci0] 41.958662
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in white list (0x01)
        PHYs: 0x01
        Entry 0: LE 1M
          Type: Passive (0x00)
          Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                      #6 [hci0] 41.959655
      LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) plen 6                  #7 [hci0] 41.959682
        Extended scan: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                      #8 [hci0] 41.960625
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) plen 6                  #9 [hci0] 83.515930
        Extended scan: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                     #10 [hci0] 83.633423
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
```

Comment: Open 2 tabs in terminal. In the 1st one type this `sudo btmon`. In the 2nd one, do the following in order, `bluetoothctl`, `scan on`, (find MAC address of your device) then, `pair AA:DD:CC:DD:EE:FF` -> This is your MAC. Share the output of the 1st tab.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay in response @Mr.Panda I will update the original post.

Comment: I see. Your keyboard is BLE `BR/EDR Not Supported`. You cannot pair due to having different authentication requirements (`Reason: Authentication requirements (0x03)`). as it is stated by Bluetooth  "The pairing procedure can not be performed as authentication requirements can not be met due to IO capabilities of one or both devices". There are several things we can try, but first do the same thing with `gatttool`. `gatttool -I` and then `connect E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB` and post the `btmon` output.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Updated again, @Mr.Panda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help from Mr. Panda (above) and a little digging around in gatttool, I successfully got it to connect.

Since the Nice!60 PCB is a BLE device, it's finicky to work with Ubuntu it seems, but I found a solution.

```
sudo gatttool -t random -b E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB -I
[E7:2D:83:06:AA:AB][LE]> connect
```

From there the device was available to pair, and it paired, no problem.

Note:
`-t` is the option to set device connection to public or random. It seems that some devices need to connect using a random LE address. `-b` is the option to give the static address to the BLE device found with `sudo hcitool lescan` or in the more thorough output found above. `-I` makes it an interactive session.

Comment: Glad it worked! One more thing. These tools are actually [deprecated.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/commit/?id=b1eb2c4cd057624312e0412f6c4be000f7fc3617). You might wanna check the source code of your BlueZ version `Bluetooth monitor ver 5.53` 5.53 in this case, in the future to debug further.

Comment: I'll check that out. Good to know!